# Language pack for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 (v11.0.61219.00 Update 5) on my Win10 machine. Every time I install it I get Italian as default language but I'd like more to work on English, so I go to Tools -> Options -> International settings and click for the language pack download, which leads to here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30681

As you can see this link is no longer mantained by Microsoft. It used to download a very small agent that actually downloaded the desired language (lots of Mbs), is there a place where I can find it again?

I tried this https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=38187 with no luck.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38187 what is wrong with this link?

Comment: It doesn't work, it says: "Microsoft Visual Studio Test Agent is required, but it is not installed on this computer. Please install it and retry". Or he asks for "Microsoft Visual Studio Test Controller " (2 files can be downloaded from that link, 2 errors). I have never seen this error and I don't think I need this stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the language pack from the free [Visual Studio Dev Essentials download](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202012) page. Sign in with your Microsoft account and join the program to be able to download the language pack:

[image]

Comment: When I login in into that site with my developer account I'm getting at this page but the page seem to loop eternally and I never get to the download result. I tried with FF and MSIE 11 to no avail.

Comment: @Krischu have you joined the  Visual Studio Dev Essentials program first?

Comment: Yes, I think I have. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to log into this site.

Comment: I just tried it with google chrome. Same picture. looping (Loading... circles no end). I search the Internet for "Visual Studio 2012 language pack" and choose the search result http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/downloads/vs-language-packs/ from which I go via the link on that page: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202012%20Language%20Pack to a login page. I login with my account and immediately land there with a prefilled in Search field resulting in Downloads(1) and the Loading loop shows.

Comment: @Krischu I have no idea why this fails for you. ask support: https://www.visualstudio.com/support/support-overview-vs